# How to model objects inside environment texture

Tags: modeling

I'm currently attempting to model the inside of a church. I have some of the rough dimensions and an equirectangular projection which I am using as an environment texture. I'm running into problems getting the objects to map onto the right places as I rotate the environment. It's probably a simple issue of scale and mapping the environment texture correctly into the scene, but I'm really not sure what the best workflow is to solve this. Are there some tools inside of blender that may make this a little easier?

I don't need a lot of detail. I really only need the walls and floor.

Comment: is your shadder like this? have uv mapping? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDIFR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDIFR.png)

Comment: could you please show some pictures? It would help to understand what you mean

Comment: BTW  why do you rotate  the envi?  ... and how.

Answer (score 3):

To get equirectangular texture mapped correctly it is usseful to know distance of the camera (that took a shots) from a ground. Usually it is about 1.5 - 1.7 m.

[image]

This should be a distance of floor face from object's origin, because  the origin represents the place of real camera and all pixela of equirectangular texture are like exploding sphere into all directions from origin location.

[image]

It is quite useful to position also *Camera* object at Plane's *Origin*. **Lock position** at X=0, Y=0, Z= Plane's Origin and enable under *3Dview* side *Properties panel* (N) *View tab* > **Camera to View**.

In *Shader editor > World* set the same equirectangular texture. Now they should match from *Camera* view.

[image]

With Plane selected switch to *Edit mode* and start to reconstruct environment ...

[image]

[image]

Note:

- Or if you know some distances you can ensure with those. Like if you know size of floor, set that in edit mode and by moving this face along global Z axis you can adjust position to match with a texture.
- and sure ... you have to use *Environment* texture node (not *Image* node) ;)
- You don't have to use a Camera setup described above, you can directly extrude faces in 3Dviewport, but gives you nice overview what is where.

Comment: Hey man, this answer is a real eye-opener for me :). I never knew you can line up your HDRI like that, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Finally some one who jumped on the same wave :) Yeah I thought it was broken for many years :) Than I realised I was just blind when I tried to reconstruct space with origin at floor level :)