# How to share node value with another node to keep them sync

Tags: node-editor, drivers

How should I setup a driver to keep two values same across blend file?
Like ...

**World** > *Mapping node > Z Rotation*  value to **Object** *> Mapping node > Z Rotation*

It would be handy in case like when you reconstruct environment from equirectangular texture set for World shader and same texture is used for an object I reconstruct [like here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210222/2214).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply copy-paste the driver, the values should be the same.

1. *RMB > Copy as New Driver* from one Mapping node
2. *RMB > Paste Driver* into the second one
3. Done.

[image]