# Using Simple Deform to bend multiple objects at the same time?

Tags: modeling

I want that I can bend/twist etc multiple separate objects using the same Simple Deform Modifier? Is that possible? That will help me organic looking models also when I do Boolean it will also modify the boolean objects too. Any insight on this?

Comment: You can join objects by geo nodes modifier and than use simple bend modifier ... Or you can set bend modifier to all selected objects from contextual menu and than set drivers with specific value in modifier to sync values.

Comment: @vklidu Can you show me how to do it in both the cases? Or direct me to a youtube video where it shows the same? (And would they have different material if joined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### version Geo Nodes

Probably even better to use **Collection Info** node (than *Join Geometry*) so you can affect all objects at once ...

... all objet you want to bend place into collection. Than add any mesh object (I used Plane) but can be anything, this mesh is not going to be a part of the result. The Plane object just has to be out of collection (that you want to bend).

[image]
[image]

[image]

### version Copy to Selected

Downside of geo nodes technique is lost of materials. To keep materials you can try use *Copy to Selected* ...

- Ad *Empty* object
- Select all objects you want to affect by bending.
- Ad **Simple Deform** modifier and choose *Empty* for *Origin* field.
- Now go to modifier header and next to camera icon open expand menu and choose **Copy to Selected**. This operator ads modifier to each selected object.

If you need to change **Angle** (with all affected objects still selected) right-click over angle value and choose *Copy to Selected* there. This operator syncs value for all Angle values in modifier of all selected objects.

This angle value can be [synchronized by drivers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211202/2214) ... its simple copy paste technique, but has to be set manually for each object. After driver assignment you can set angle and see effect in real time for all objects.

Comment: Do I need to join the separate objects first? Because when i put 2 objects in a collection and apple Geometry node to one of the objects and do exactly the same what you did it only affects the object where i have applied the Simple deform node. (I am getting error "Collection contains current object")

Comment: See edit for more info ...

Comment: Thanks ... for the model.

Comment: Hi, i forgot to ask, how do i add different colours to separate objects? Using set material in geometry node applies the same colour to entire model.

Comment: See edit for more info ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example what vklidu meant:

[image]