# Automaticly merge multiple frames from a camera projection into one

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor, motion-capture

I have tracked my camera and recreated the scene mesh on which I am projecting the frame of the image sequence.
[image: image shows the projection, using the UVProject modifier, and tracking]

If I step some frames back the camera "sees" something different. A different area is textured. How can I now automatically merge these different projections into one so I get a continuously textured model?
[image: projection shown on a different frame]

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKUOM67hOkU&list=PL4EqKJjrgoVSySMHdLXIbptCYvyImXYHY&index=3) tutorial of CGMatter explaining the process but for a scene where multiple textures are needed, this is quite a labour-intensive job.
Is there any way to automate or speed that process up?
I am aware of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76774/projecting-multiple-images-onto-an-object-with-uv-project-modifiers) StackExchange question but I do not really understand it and it's quite old too.
Thank you for your help appreciate it a lot. :)

Comment: I would suggest use [shader for projection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/226920/2214) instead of modifier that generates distortions. Also merging several projections in shader sounds to me probably easier. BTW ... Next time plan a bit if possible and spend a minute to capture spherical 360 deg environment texture ... [easy to reconstruct](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210222/2214)

Comment: Yea, I usually take a HDRI but this was a quick shot in the train station. but thanks for the shader idea did not think of that